# Updating RDF data using php on sesame server

Tags: php, sparql, sesame

I have a question about updating RDF data using PHP code on sesame server.
I have tried to use the SPARQL update from sesame endpoint and successed. However, using PHP it didn't gave any error but when I check the RDF data nothing change!!

in the connecting, I have used this link to proceed the update:
http://localhost:8080/Sesame/repositories/MyData/statements

and the following code to achieve the update:

```
$query= "
DELETE DATA{
  ?s foaf:firstName \"Lina\".
}
WHERE {
  ?s foaf:firstName \"Lina\".
}";


$result = $sparql->query($query);
```

I thought I have to change query function now since now, it is not query and it is update. Additionally, I have tried

```
$result = $sparql->update($query);
```

and I got an error!!

what is wrong or what should I do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are confusing/mixing `DELETE DATA` and `DELETE WHERE` - which are different types of update operations in SPARQL. Simply remove the `DATA` keyword from your query, like so:

```
$query= "
DELETE {
  ?s foaf:firstName \"Lina\".
}
WHERE {
  ?s foaf:firstName \"Lina\".
}";
```

This will remove all statements with predicate `foaf:firstName` and object `"Lina"`.

And since you want to delete the exact triples you're matching, you do not have to repeat the graph pattern in the `DELETE` clause, so your query can become shorter:

```
$query= "
    DELETE 
    WHERE {
      ?s foaf:firstName \"Lina\".
    }";
```

Comment: I got it now. Thank you(:

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem as I have tried to use the delete command without any variable (?s), and instead use the actual subject such:

```
$query= "DELETE DATA{ds:S1 foaf:firstName \"Lina\".}";
```

I think that is because you can't delete something you don't know.
and I used the following to execute it:

```
$result = $sparql->update($query);
```

Comment: While this works, the variable in your query is actually not the problem - and it's not true that you "can't delete something you don't know". See my answer for details.

Comment: Also worth noting: this update does something different from the one in your question - it deletes one specific statement, while the `DELETE...WHERE` update deletes _all_ statements that match. It may of course be the case that there only is one statement with that precise predicate and object-value in your actual dataset, but if you're unsure about that, be careful about which approach you actually need.

Comment: Make sense, Thank you